# Anchor-tags not working

Tags: html, anchor

The anchor tags on every page of my Wordpress website are not working.
I understand how to do them, for example on my contact page, I have

```
<a href="#end"></a>
```

around the mail image. It is linked to before the "thank you" at the end of the page with:

```
<a id="end"></a>
```

When the mail image is clicked the link does not execute. If I type in the direct link to the jump, it works.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your page source you have the following:

```
<a id="end"></a>
```

It should be:

```
<a name="end"></a>
```

It's worth noting though that the `name` attribute of the `<a>` tag is deprecated as of HTML5. Therefore to be HTML5 compliant I'd suggest the following:

```
<h2 id="end">some text at the end</h2>
```

Note the element can be anything you want. Usually a header tag or similar though.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. If you don't mind me asking, why should I be using name instead of id?

Comment: @user48491 glad to hear it! If you feel it has answered your question, please feel free to accept it by clicking the tick beside my answer. The reason it's `name` and not `id` is because that's what was chosen! FYI `name` on `<a>` tags is deprecated as of HTML5, I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: "name" attribute of "a" tag is deprecated in html5